# Replace 'for loop' using std::for_each

Tags: c++, std

I have a for loop in the below code and I would like to implement it using std::for_each. I have implemented it. Could someone please tell me if that is the best way to do it using std::for_each? If not, could you please suggest the right one?

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::uint32_t> nums{3, 4, 2, 8, 15};
    std::stringstream list1;


    for (auto n : nums)
    {
        list1 << n<<",";
    }

    //Is this the right way to do using std::for_each so that above for loop can be done in 1 line??
    std::for_each(nums.begin(),nums.end(),[&list1](std::uint32_t n){ list1 << n << ","; });

}
```

Comment: You've overloaded `operator<<` for `std::vector<T>` and `T` and even `const char*`? `std::vector` doesn't store commas, you know. This is not an interpreted language.

Comment: This doesn't compile even when relevant headers are added as `std::vector<std::uint32_t>` doesn't have operator `<<` defined.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. I have updated the code. I hope it will compile now

Comment: Have you thought about, umm... compiling it yourself?

Comment: Neither. This could be a [simple bind expression](http://ideone.com/m6pQgs).

Comment: Why `std::uint32_t`? Is there a requirement that this code only runs on systems with a 32-bit integral hardware type? Use `unsigned long`; it exists on all systems and is required to be at least 32 bits. Or, if you **really, really** like the explicitly sized types, use `std::uint_least32_t` or `std::uint_fast32_t`, both of which are required to exist on all platforms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your use of `for_each` is a reasonable analog of the preceding loop.

I feel obliged to point out, however, that I find `for_each` probably the *least* useful algorithm in the library. From what I've seen, using it generally indicates that you're still basically *thinking* in terms of loops, and just changing the syntax you use for those loops. I also think that range-based `for` loops have probably eliminated at least 90% of the (already few) legitimate uses there used to be for `for_each`.

In this case, your code is really imitating using `std::copy` with an `std::ostream_iterator`:

```
std::copy(nums.begin(), nums.end(), 
          std::ostream_iterator<std::uint32_t>(std::cout, ","));
```

Even this, however, is clumsy enough that I think it's open to question whether it's really an improvement over a range-based `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just test it out?

[`auto`](http://goo.gl/goCN04) vs [`std::for_each`](http://goo.gl/4vXRjq)

As you can see the assembly output is the same for both. It just doesn't make any difference for your example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tested it. I get the result. I wanted to know if there is a better way to do using std::for_each.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy the data from one thing to another you can use [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy)

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::uint32_t> nums{3, 4, 2, 8, 15};
    std::stringstream list1;

    std::copy(nums.begin(), nums.end(),std::ostream_iterator<std::uint32_t>(list1,","));
    std::cout << list1.str();
}
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/045239344e36043a)</kbd>

This will end the stream with a `,` but that is the same thing you get in you code.

If you do not want this then you should look at [Pretty-print C++ STL containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850473/pretty-print-c-stl-containers)

Comment: thanks for your answer. Since you mentioned about the comma at the end, is there any method to avoid that?

Answer (score -4):

Yes, that is right. There is no need for the reference in `(std::uint32_t &n)` if you had performance as the motive.

Comment: This code won't compile as is so how can it be correct?